# Passing arguments to vim.api.nvim_create_user_command in order to execute a bash command

Tags: lua, neovim

I've been using mproc in server mode to start a bunch of project dependencies in the background.

mproc is currently running in the background with the server receiving commands at 127.0.0.1:4050. It started four services for me: docker, red, blue, green.

I want to interact with server without leaving neovim. I was able to partially accomplish this with the following code

```lua
local ECP_SERVICE_CODE = {
    DOCKER = 0,
    RED = 1,
    BLUE = 2,
    GREEN = 3,
}

local MPROC_CMDS = {
    RESTART = "restart",
    KILL = "kill"
}

function EcpMproc(service, command)
    return [[!mprocs --server 127.0.0.1:4050 --ctl '{c: batch, cmds:[{c: select-proc, index: ]] ..
        tostring(service) .. [[}, {c: ]] .. tostring(command) .. [[-proc }, {c: select-proc, index: 0}]}'<cr>]]
end


vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("ColorsRedServiceKill", ColorsMproc(ECP_SERVICE_CODE.RED, MPROC_CMDS.KILL), {})
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("ColorsRedServiceRestart", ColorsMproc(ECP_SERVICE_CODE.RED, MPROC_CMDS.RESTART), {})

vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("ColorsBlueServiceKill", ColorsMproc(ECP_SERVICE_CODE.BLUE, MPROC_CMDS.KILL), {})
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("ColorsBlueServiceRestart", ColorsMproc(ECP_SERVICE_CODE.BLUE, MPROC_CMDS.RESTART), {})

vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("ColorsGreenServiceKill", ColorsMproc(ECP_SERVICE_CODE.GREEN, MPROC_CMDS.KILL), {})
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command("ColorsGreenServiceRestart", ColorsMproc(ECP_SERVICE_CODE.GREEN, MPROC_CMDS.RESTART), {})
```

I can now interact with my running mproc instance by using commands like `:ColorsRedServiceKill<CR>` or `:ColorsBlueServiceRestart<CR>`.

Without worrying so much about robustness or corner cases, I want to be able to make use of the argument passing to neovim commands and instead call this function with something more along the lines of `:Colors 1 restart` or better yet (`:Colors blue restart`)

Here's my best go at this. It's not having the desired effects :(

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command(
    "Colors",
    function(opts)
        local service = opts.fargs[1]
        local command = opts.fargs[2]

        return ColorsMproc(service, command)
    end,
    {nargs = "+", bang = true}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you shouldn't need to use `return`.
I'm also assuming that `ColorsMproc` is defined already somewhere else in the .lua files, otherwise you'd need to access it with `vim.fn` (I'm pretty sure). So then it may look something like this:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command(
    "Colors",
    function()
        local service = vim.fn.input "service: "
        local command = vim.fn.input "command: "

        ColorsMproc(service, command)
    end,
    {nargs = "+", bang = true}
)
```

I think you can put 'service' and 'command' in the same line by doing something like:
`local sc = vim.split(vim.fn.input "service/command: ", " ")`.

I was referencing this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlfjpstqXwE